# Why does open() fails every time with EAGAIN?

Tags: linux, apache2, strace

Why would a program like Apache fail to open a plain file? Running it under `strace` shows:

```
open("access.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 11
```

`11` stands for either `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`

Where:

```
$ ls -l access.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 2 Jun  9 17:52 access.log
```

If I `su` as `www-data` I can write to the file safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`11` is the file descriptor not an error code. Which means the `open` calls you are seeing have succeeded not failed. If `open` fails it will return `-1` and strace would show something like this:

```
open("access.log", O_RDONLY)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```